# Jquery Blur text and empty on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple text box like this. I want to apply the text on blur and empty when it get focused. I can able to achieve this for single text box. How i can pass the current element id instead of the hard coding the "#name" value in JavaScript function ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#Name').focus(function()
    {
         var $ele = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css('color', '#000000');
    });

    $('#Name').blur(function()
    {
           var $ele = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).val($ele);
            $(this).css('color', '#a9a9a9')
    });
});



<input id="Name" type="text" value="" name="Name">
<input id="Phone" type="text" value="" name="Phone" >
<input id="Email" type="text" value="" name="Email">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all input by `$('input')` and you can put filter text inputs using `[type="text"]`; You can take benefits of jQuery chaining.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('input[type="text"]').focus(function()
    {
         var $ele = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css('color', '#000000');
    }).blur(function()
    {
           var $ele = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).val($ele);
            $(this).css('color', '#a9a9a9')
    });
});
```

You can directly set value of input fields in html

```
<input id="Name" type="text" value="Name" name="Name">
```

OR Apply default values on page load as:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
   var $ele = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).val($ele);
                $(this).css('color', '#a9a9a9')

});
```

HTML

```
<input id="Name" type="text" value="" name="Name">
<input id="Phone" type="text" value="" name="Phone" >
<input id="Email" type="text" value="" name="Email">
```

Comment: Its working now, oncei get focus and lost focus. How can i apply the text by default of page load ?. Right now coded inside document.Ready!!!..

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify you js

```
$(function(){
    $('input').focus(function()
    {
        $(this)
            .val($(this).attr('name'))
            .css('color', '#000000')

    }).blur(function()
    {
            $(this).css('color', '#a9a9a9')
    });
})();​
```

if you set value on 'blur' you will lost current value... I am not sure that it is exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

apply it to `input` instead of `#name`.

this will work for all inputs.

or give a `.class` to the elements you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You may select all inputs with `$('input[type="text"]')`, but I think you just want to use the [`placeholder` HTML attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Look into [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
What you're doing now is using the ID as the selector.  You have tons of different options...

You can replace "#Name" with "input" if you want it to apply to all inputs on the page, or you could even add a common class 'class="test"' to all the elements you want to trigger the script and then replace the "#Name" with ".test" or "input.test" for only input elements with that class name.